# How to backup an iOS enterprise app and install on multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, backup, restore, enterprise

The question is not about programming. It is related to back-up of an iOS enterprise app(not AppStore) and installing it to multiple devices.

Can we back-up an enterprise app along with its Document-Directory and then port that backed-up app to the multiple iOS devices along with the data in Document-Directory?

I can do the first part easily I guess, but when it is coupled with the second part then it seems tricky.

Please share any information regarding this. Would be very helpful.

Comment: I assume you have some sample files in apps document dir that you want to be available when app is installed. Why not include all those files in app's bundle and upon first time app launch copy all those files over to apps-document-dir? This is pretty easy to do

Comment: If you have a qualified iOS Enterprise account, then you can put your .ipa application on a web server and distribute it to all your employees by letting them download it.  If you have an additional MDM software, you can even have all your employee devices registered and push new versions of your app out to them.  Check out Apple's enterprise program:

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I know about both the options but this is the weird requirement that I have in one of my apps. is it possible ?

Comment: you found a solution ? I've the same issue. Employees creates new Data in document folder. I hoped that the app data was saved to the icloud when iOS is doing an app data backup. But looks like is not happening with Enterprise Apps.

Comment: I had posted an answer at that time. I got it done using Apple Configurator for my requirement. You can check it out, however may not be a solution for you considering the Cloud and your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - **Apple Configurator**

The device back-up feature can be used to restore and back-up an app along-with its data.

More is [here](http://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/1.5/#cadbf9b61c)